# Recursive looping of components in angular2 which has control arrays as input

Tags: angular

I want to recursively loop a the template of components which has an ControlArray and an array as input. I am adding these controls to the parent control group here http://plnkr.co/edit/5GZzLYbHA1k5KgK8DU9x?p=preview

The problem is when I apply `ngFor` for on the template the text is repeated in the wrong place. What is wrong in this plunker demo which makes the data to appear in wrong place?

When I submit the form I am getting the data perfectly but the view is not correct. What is the best way to pass the control array in the recursively looped template?

```html
<div *ngFor="#Array of ChangedDataForm;#i=index">
    <complaint [ComplaintsControl]="Form.controls['Complaints']" [ComplaintsData]='Array.Complaint'></complaint><br>
    <div *ngFor="#Opdata of Array.Complaint[0].Operations;#j=index">
        <operations [OperationsData]='Opdata' [OperationsControl]="Form.controls['Operations']"></operations>
        <br>
        <div *ngFor="#partsData of Opdata[j].Parts">
           <Parts [ServicePartsData]='partsData' [servicePartsControl]="Form.controls['Parts']"></Parts>
        </div><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I am passing control array and the data into the child components. When I pass the control array the child components add control groups to the array.

Comment: `#` in `*ngFor` is outdated. It should be `let `. What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: What steps are required to reproduce with the Plunker. What is the right place to repeat the text? What text?

Comment: I have been using beta.15...

Comment: I want the output to display in a hierarchical order like->   
1)Complaint should display first
2)If a Complaint has any Operations then it should be displayed
3)Each Operation can have parts init which should be displayed after that Operation.I want the user interface to look like this but i dont know how to create controlGroup/Control Arrays for this kind of a structure